# 15 Link Only Answers to one question!

Tags: discussion

I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833/what-is-the-single-best-article-on-the-web-for-programmers/46947#46947), asked 4 years back, with almost all answers (15) as a link.

I wonder is acceptable to have a question of this kind in StackOverflow, shouldn't all answers be flagged and then question get deleted?

*I voted to delete.*

Comment: 50 rep says it gets deleted in 3, 2, 1, ...

Comment: One minute and 16 seconds.

Comment: Good work, soldiers. One down, one million to go...

Comment: Such questions have been locked and marked as having historical significance, why delete this one? (It was edited by Joel himself so I assume it was okay back then?)

Comment: @GSerg - Not everything from the olden days has historical significance. This certainly doesn't look like it does. Not with the score of 13...